# How can I reference Mule home directory in java component

Tags: java, mule

How can I reference the home directory of Mule in a Java component, for instance:

```
String directory = ${Mule_Home};
```

Comment: have you created Environment variable for this(Mule_Home)?

Comment: I am not familiar with mule, but is this a system-wide environment variable? In other words, would `System.getProperty(...)` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you can do this is to first save the value of #[mule.home] in a variable:

```
    <set-variable value="#[mule.home]" variableName="mule_home"
        doc:name="Variable" />
```

and then you can access this from the component as follows:

```
    MuleMessage message = eventContext.getMessage();
    String mule_home = message.getProperty("mule_home", PropertyScope.INVOCATION);
```

Another way, which is actually better, is to implement MuleContextAware and evaluate the mule expression in your component as follows:

```
public class MyComponent implements Callable, MuleContextAware {

MuleContext context;

@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {

    ExpressionLanguage el = context.getExpressionLanguage();
    String result = el.evaluate("mule.home");
    return result;
}

@Override
public void setMuleContext(MuleContext context) {
    this.context = context;
}
// include getters and setters for context
```

Comment: why would you want to set a variable in Mule flow? It wont be required in entire mule flow after this, and If it is required in multiple different flows? then ? set it in every flow?

Comment: I've modified my answer so as to include a better way how to get mule home. HTH

Answer (score 1):

One approach here can be to set environment variable by the name 'MULE_HOME'

and to retrieve it in your java component using :-

```
System.getenv("MULE_HOME");
```

hope it helps!
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to what Clare mentioned above, you can simply call the method on the MuleContext that directly gives you the full path to the MULE_HOME directory as an alternative to using the ExpressionLanguage.evaluate() method.

```
public class MyComponent implements Callable, MuleContextAware {

MuleContext context;

@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    return context.getConfiguration().getMuleHomeDirectory();
}

@Override
public void setMuleContext(MuleContext context) {
    this.context = context;
}
// include getters and setters for context
```